# Knockout JS with Razor layout

Tags: razor, knockout.js

**Dev and libraries**

- ASP.NET 5
- Razor
- KnockoutJS

I am building a dashboard and I want to create a knockoutjs filter of when you switch clients. The data will update for just that client. The dropdown for the client will be in the _Layout.cshtml file. Here is the code I have for that:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<ul id="clients" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user" data-bind="foreach: storeList()">
    <li>
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: '#'}, text: storeList.ClientName"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**_Dashboard.cshtml**

```
$.getJSON("/System/GetClients", function (clientList) {
    function Event(event) {
        var self = this;
        self.event = ko.observable(event);
    }

    function EventsModel() {
        ...

        self.storeList = ko.computed(function () {
            return clientList;
        });

        $('#clients').unbind();
        ko.applyBindings(self, $('#clients'));

        ...
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new EventsModel());
});
```

I think the problem lies is the foreach: storeList is bound before the data is received. When I look at the page there are no errors in the console. The dropdown has 6 li > a elements as it should but they are not rendered

```
<ul id="clients" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user" data-bind="foreach: storeList()">
    <li>
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: '#'}, text: storeList.ClientName" href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: '#'}, text: storeList.ClientName" href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: '#'}, text: storeList.ClientName" href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: '#'}, text: storeList.ClientName" href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: '#'}, text: storeList.ClientName" href="#"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the stringify version of the clientList

```
[{"ClientName":"admin","Description":"Admin Sample Account","Enable":true},{"ClientName":"DSG","Description":"DSG TEST","Enable":true},{"ClientName":"Pet","Description":"PetTEST","Enable":true},{"ClientName":"Test","Description":"Test Sample Account","Enable":true},{"ClientName":"Toys","Description":"Toy's","Enable":true}]
```

Not sure what is wrong

Comment: `since the code is not in the same file` can you elaborate on this . i am unable to get the catch .

Comment: Please do post the knockout code too.

Comment: Just updated with newest code I have

Comment: Can please post a sample of what one of the objects in the `storeList` looks like.

Comment: Done. Got it updateed

Comment: I figured it out. I had to call ClientName instead of storeList.ClientName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

storeList is a computed observable. As such, it's OK to treat it as a function in the foreach. Your mistake occurs on the a tags.

- you're calling again storeList, which is wrong. Apart, you're using it as a getter property, but it's a function.

Just use a with the ClientName property, without clientList.ClientName and you're done.

Knockout is rendering the elements correctly,as you can see a list of li elements rendered